# Cannot resolve RDOAddressEntry using Outlook Redemption

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I wrote a C# Windows Form app that used a previous version of Outlook Redemption to send emails that bypass the Outlook security messages. It worked great until I upgraded to 64-bit Outlook 2013 from 32-bit Outlook 2010. Now, I'm using the 64-bit Outlook Redemption DLL, version 5.10.0.4416, with 64-bit Outlook 2013, on Windows 64-bit, and I'm receiving a "Cannot resolve" error, error code `-2147221233/8004010F`.

The code below worked great when I was using 32-bit Outlook with the 32-bit Outlook Redemption DLL (on Windows 64-bit). I've updated my reference to use the 64-bit Outlook Redemption DLL and updated my application solution to x64.

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.Logon(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
bool loggedOn = session.LoggedOn;                        // Debug, true
RDOFolder draft = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
string smtp = session.CurrentWindowsUser.SMTPAddress);   // Debug, valid user@mycompany.com
RDOAddressEntry smtpAddress = session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName(session.CurrentWindowsUser.SMTPAddress);
```

The `RDOAddressEntry smtpAddress = session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName(session.CurrentWindowsUser.SMTPAddress);` line is the line that is receiving the error.

Also, the `loggedOn` variable indicates `true` and the `session.CurrentWindowsUser.SMTPAddress` shows the email address when I debug.

If I'm not mistaken, the `8004010F` error indicates that an item was not found. If that's true, then I'm not sure why the exact same code worked with 32-bit Outlook, 32-bit Outlook Redemption, on 64-bit Windows and won't work with 64-bit Outlook, 64-bit Outlook Redemption, and 64-bit Windows.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

GAL container won't resolve the SMTP address in the PR_ANR restriction that GAL.ResolveName uses. Either use `RDOSession.AddressBook.ResolveName` (note here is no GAL part) or pass the display name instead.

Comment: Is that new with Outlook 2013? Just curious why it worked for me with Outlook 2010 for so long.

Comment: That's really strange that it worked using GAL when the app was run every month for two years. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I don't know why it worked - I never could resolve SMTP address in GAL. I always had to use RDOSession.AddressBook.ResolveName .